# Python's __import__ doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-import

When using `__import__` with a dotted name, something like: `somepackage.somemodule`, the module returned isn't `somemodule`, whatever is returned seems to be mostly empty! what's going on here?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the python docs on `__import__`:

> ```
> __import__( name[, globals[, locals[, fromlist[, level]]]])
> ```
>
> ...
>
> When the name variable is of the form
>   package.module, normally, the
>   top-level package (the name up till
>   the first dot) is returned, not the
>   module named by name. However, when a
>   non-empty fromlist argument is given,
>   the module named by name is returned.
>   This is done for compatibility with
>   the bytecode generated for the
>   different kinds of import statement;
>   when using "import spam.ham.eggs", the
>   top-level package spam  must be placed
>   in the importing namespace, but when
>   using "from spam.ham import eggs", the
>   spam.ham subpackage must be used to
>   find the eggs variable. As a
>   workaround for this behavior, use
>   getattr() to extract the desired
>   components. For example, you could
>   define the following helper:
>
> ```
> def my_import(name):
>     mod = __import__(name)
>     components = name.split('.')
>     for comp in components[1:]:
>         mod = getattr(mod, comp)
>     return mod
> ```

**To paraphrase:**

When you ask for `somepackage.somemodule`, `__import__` returns `somepackage.__init__.py`, which is often empty.

It will return `somemodule` if you provide `fromlist` (a list of the variable names inside `somemodule` you want, which are not actually returned)

You can also, as I did, use the function they suggest.

Note: I asked this question fully intending to answer it myself. There was a big bug in my code, and having misdiagnosed it, it took me a long time to figure it out, so I figured I'd help the SO community out and post the gotcha I ran into here.

Answer (score 32):

python 2.7 has importlib, dotted paths resolve as expected

```
import importlib
foo = importlib.import_module('a.dotted.path')
instance = foo.SomeClass()
```

Comment: There's also a python 2.6 package which backports this functionality.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib/

Answer (score 16):

There is a simpler solution, as explained in the documentation:

If you simply want to import a module (potentially within a package) by name, you can call __import__() and then look it up in sys.modules:

```
>>> import sys
>>> name = 'foo.bar.baz'
>>> __import__(name)
<module 'foo' from ...>
>>> baz = sys.modules[name]
>>> baz
<module 'foo.bar.baz' from ...>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is something that works as you want it to: `twisted.python.reflect.namedAny`:

```
>>> from twisted.python.reflect import namedAny
>>> namedAny("operator.eq")
<built-in function eq>
>>> namedAny("pysqlite2.dbapi2.connect")
<built-in function connect>
>>> namedAny("os")
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.5/os.pyc'>
```

Comment: That's very useful, however I don't really have any other need for twisted in my program. Although, as the founder (!), you are probably more knowledgeable of the possibilities than me (never used it).

Answer (score 1):

For python 2.6, I wrote this snippet:

```
def import_and_get_mod(str, parent_mod=None):
    """Attempts to import the supplied string as a module.
    Returns the module that was imported."""
    mods = str.split('.')
    child_mod_str = '.'.join(mods[1:])
    if parent_mod is None:
        if len(mods) > 1:
            #First time this function is called; import the module
            #__import__() will only return the top level module
            return import_and_get_mod(child_mod_str, __import__(str))
        else:
            return __import__(str)
    else:
        mod = getattr(parent_mod, mods[0])
        if len(mods) > 1:
            #We're not yet at the intended module; drill down
            return import_and_get_mod(child_mod_str, mod)
        else:
            return mod
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did is

```
foo = __import__('foo',  globals(), locals(), ["bar"], -1)
foobar = eval("foo.bar")
```

then i can access any content from by

```
foobar.functionName()
```