# Create an import statement using variable "interpolation"

Tags: python, import, string-interpolation

I have a long list of possible files I need to import.  I will only ever need 1 of them and they all have the same interface.  (Choosing a payment gateway to process a payment)

Suppose I have a dictionary that represents the name of all the gateway files.

i.e.

```
gateways = {
   '1' : 'authorize',
   '2' : 'paysimple',
   '3' : 'braintreepayments',
   '4' : 'etc',
}
```

I know the keys to this dictionary based on information from a database.  So, if I receive a payment process request with a gateway value of 1 I know it needs to be handled by Authorize.net.  A 2 is to be processed by Pay Simple.  Etc.

I'd like to be able to create an import statement that is built with the information I know rather than a horrible list of `elif` statements.

Consider the simple method below:

```
# For the purposes of this example assume payment_gateway is defined
# elsewhere and represents the key to the dictionary
gateway_file = gateways.get(payment_gateway)

import_str = "from gateway_interface.%s import process" % gateway_file
gogo(import_str)
```

Where `gogo` is a way to cause the import statement to actually import.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Are you sure your process only handles one payment and then exits?  That sounds unusual.

Comment: I'm not sure how that is unusual.  If you do online shopping and request a checkout why would you process the transaction with more than one gateway?

Comment: You would only use one at a time, but typically online shopping would be handled by a long-running process that handles many requests over its lifetime.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder Can you elaborate on that idea?  I'm not sure I understand why leaving the process running would be advantageous.  We are using Django and posting to a view, which will spawn this process.  Do you suggest a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest

```
process = __import__('gateway_interface.'+gateway_file,fromlist=['foo']).process
```

**EDIT**: 'foo' in the fromlist can be anything, as long as fromlist is not an emptylist. That little bit of strangeness is explained in [Why does Python's __import__ require fromlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724260/why-does-pythons-import-require-fromlist).

I also had to edit because in my first post  `__import__` didn't work as expected as further described in [Python's __import__ doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211100/pythons-import-doesnt-work-as-expected).

if you have python 2.7

```
import importlib
process = importlib.import_module('gateway_interface.'+gateway_file).process
```

WAAAAY cool would be to use package_tools (e.g. `from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points`)

That could give you a solution to find the right function even if they are in odd packages not under gateway_interface.  If they are all on one place and you don't need the sytle-point that is overkill so ... yeah just `__import__`

Comment: This isn't quite working for me, and I'm not sure what I've done wrong.  I'm getting the following error: `'module' object has no attribute 'process'`

Comment: I'll test, not sure which of the two approaches you tried.  is there an `__init__.py` in the gateway_file subdir?

Comment: Everything is within the same module `gateway_interface`.  The file I need to import has a class called `process` that I need to instantiate.  Yes, `gateway_interface` has `__init__.py`.

Comment: <slaps forehead> I fixed the getattr version.  I also added the fromlist keyword to `__import__`.  I'll post an edit in the answer to explain why that is needed but it's the difference between a package vs a module import.  The current edit should work. <he said with confidence and authority as he crossed his fingers>

Comment: Yes, awesome!  I actually tried this both pre-2.7 and the `importlib` way.  I like the latter.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module which allows you to access the internals of the import statement, or the [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) method itself - either of these should allow you to achieve what you describe I think.

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `__import__` method should work:

```
process = __import__(gateways.get(payment_gateway)).process
```