# Creating a custom import statement which accepts variables, used to import django models

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a simple script used to generate fixture data for a given django model. I cannot figure out how to create an import statement which accepts user input, to allow me to perform the actual logic on the selected model.

I've tried various combinations of `imp`, `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location`,
`importlib.import_module`,
`__import__`,
[Create an import statement using variable "interpolation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404617/create-an-import-statement-using-variable-interpolation)

The closest I've gotten is:

```py
def import_function(app, model):
    exec(f"from {app}.models import {model}")
    exec(f"print({model}.objects.all())") #This works.
import_function("home", "Person")
```

My thinking is: I create a module called 'fixture.py'. Within that module is a custom import function. I import the module into the environment created by 
`python manage.py shell` so as to obviate the need for modifying the PATH.
Then, I call the function using `fixture.import_function(app, model)`.

I've managed to generate the fixture data this way, but only when I'm hardcoding the import statement, i.e. `from home.models import Person`.
`#fixture generating logic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong approach. There's no need to fiddle with imports or construct names dynamically. Use the functions that Django provides to find the model:

```
from django.apps import apps
model = apps.get_model(app, model)
print(model.objects.all())
```